# prove P ∧ Q → P ⇔ R ∨ ¬R in natural deduction

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I am a beginner in Natural Deduction currently reading the book "Logic in Computer Science" and got stuck at proving:
$$ P\land Q\to P\Leftrightarrow R\lor\lnot R$$

The latter formula is clearly a LEM, which I think $R$ should be obtained by getting a contradiction in the former formula.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot obtain a contradiction from $P ∧ Q → P$, because it is a *tautology*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See :

- Michael Huth & Mark Ryan, [Logic in Computer Science : Modelling and Reasoning about Systems](https://books.google.it/books?id=sVLOaObSBHkC&pg=PA27) (2nd ed 2004), page 27 for the table of natural deduction rules.

(A) *LEM* is a $0$-premise rule in the system; thus, we have a $1$-line proof of :

> $\vdash r \lor \lnot r$.

(B) $p \land q \to p$ is a *tautology*, thus it must be provable :

1) $p \land q$ --- assumed [a]

2) $p$ --- from 1) by $\land$-e

> 3) $\vdash p \land q \to p$ --- from 1) and 3) by $\to$-i, discharging [a].

Now, we can use the (obvious) property of the *derivability* relation : $\vdash \ $ [not present in the book; we can see it in : Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA37) (5th ed - 2013), page 37] :

> if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \cup \Delta \vdash \varphi$,

to add to the above proofs the "unnecessary" premises, getting from (A) :

> $p \land q \to p \vdash r \lor \lnot r$

and from (B) :

> $r \lor \lnot r \vdash p \land q \to p$.

Now we can conclude with :

> > $p \land q \to p \dashv \vdash r \lor \lnot r$.

Comment: I am sorry I still don't quite get r∨¬r ⊢ p∧q→p
I thought (B) just shows p∧q→p ⊢ p∧q→p ?

Comment: @Elliot : NO; (B) shows $ ⊢ p∧q→p$ without assumptions, because it is a tautology, i.e. a "law of logic".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$$ p\wedge q\rightarrow p \leftrightarrow r \vee -r$$
$$ (-(p\wedge q)\vee p )\leftrightarrow V $$ 
If $ (-(p\wedge q)\vee p )$ is true or false, the result will be true or false respectivally, so
$$ (-p \vee -q \vee p)$$ 
$$(-q \vee -p\vee p)$$
$$(-q \vee V)=V$$